# Prove that $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}})|_{p}$ is a basis of $T_{p}M$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

So I'm reading about manifolds, and I'm coming to terms with the definitions and all - more specifically, the tangent space $T_{p}M$ - which is a set of mappings, which map a smooth function through $p$ (more precisely, an equivalence class of functions, but as far as I understand, we still write $f$ instead of $[f]$, like in $L^{p}$ spaces), into a number, and which are linear and satisfy Leibniz's identity.

Now, with that definition, I understand that $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}})|_{p}$, given a local chart $(U, \phi)$ where $p \in U$, defined by $$(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}})|_{p}(f) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}(f \circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))$$ are objects which belong to $T_{p}M$.

However, I don't see why this is a basis of $T_{p}M$. Why is this so? Given an element $X \in T_{p}M$ , can anyone write out the specific scalars $c_{1},...,c_{n}$ for which $$X = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{i} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}})|_{p}?  $$

Comment: Assume for simplicity that $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, and $p = 0$. Then, $c_i = X(x_i)$, where $x_i: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x_i(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = a_i$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the induced tangent map of a map between manifolds? Also known as the differential or the pushforward?

Comment: And also, does it make sense if we take $M = \mathbb R^n$, or is there also a difficulty there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the Taylor's theorem. Since chart maps are local diffeomorphisms, we can assume that $M = \mathbb{R^n}$. Without loss of generality, assume that $p = 0$. Take any $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Apply Taylor's theorem to get

$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0) \cdot x_1 + \ldots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(0) \cdot x_n + \sum_{i,j} h_{ij} (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot x_i x_j
$$

for some $h_{i,j}$ such that $\lim_{\mathbf{x} \to 0} h_{i,j}(\mathbf{x}) = 0$.

Consider any $X \in T_p M$. We have 
$$
X(f) = X(f(0)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0) \cdot X(x_1) + \ldots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(0) \cdot X(x_n) + \sum_{i,j} X(h_{ij} (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot x_i x_j).
$$

Let $c_i = X(x_i)$. These will be your basis coordinates. It's enough to prove that $X(h_{ij} (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot x_i x_j) = 0$. But this follows from Leibniz property of $X$ (try proving it yourself).

Comment: So the $(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ are formally $\phi(p)$, where $(U, \phi)$ is a chart which contains $p$? Oh, I see, no they're not. They're $\phi(q)$, where $q$ are other points of $U$, right?

Comment: So if I were to write the first line down without the assumption $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, would it be $$(f \circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(q)) = f(p) + \frac{\partial(f \circ \phi^{-1})}{\partial x_{1}}(\phi(p)) \pi_{1}(\phi(q)) + ... + \frac{\partial(f \circ \phi^{-1})}{\partial x_{n}}(\phi(p)) \pi_{n}(\phi(q)) + \sum_{i,j} h_{ij}(\pi_{1}(\phi(q)),...,\pi_{n}(\phi(q))) \pi_{i}(\phi(q)) \pi_{j}(\phi(q))?$$ If I'm correct, what I don't understand is, how, formally, we'd be able to take $X$ of that expression. I'm sorry for being so  nitpicky, but I'm new to this and I'm trying to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: Left hand side is just a function of $q \in M$. Right hand side is also a function of $q \in M$. We can take $X$ of any function defined in some neighborhood around $p$.

Comment: I see, thank you! So, still formally speaking, if I wanted to prove that $X_{p}(h_{ij}(\pi_{1}(\phi(\cdot)),...,\pi_{n}(\phi(\cdot))) \pi_{i}(\phi(\cdot)) \pi_{j}(\phi(\cdot)) ) = 0$, I would use the Leibnitz property to get a sum of three numbers, each of which is a multiple of $\pi_{i}(\phi(p))$ or $\pi_{j}(\phi(p))$, and because these are $0$, the whole $X_{p}(...)$ is also $0$, right? So in order to have that, I'd have to make sure that $\phi$ maps $p$ to $(0,...,0)$, which I can easily do by translation. Is this the way to do it, or is that a loss of generality?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Just as you say, applying linear transformation allows you to always assume that your chart always maps $p$ to $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Alternatively, you can write out the Taylor expansion around any other point $a$ instead of around 0, then you'll get things like $(x_i-a_i)(x_j - a_j)$ in the expansion, and you'll get 0 just the same after applying Leibniz rule when you evaluate these expressions on $a$ instead of on $0$ like we do here.

Comment: Expanding around other point just makes the thing a whole lot more messy than it already is, especially if you insist on writing it in terms of charts and projections.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much for your patience. I know writing everything out explicitly is messy, and I avoid that when I can, but I was just having a really hard time with this, so I wanted to be 100% sure I understood it. Again, thank you very much!